# @font-face completely bugging

Tags: css, font-face

I'm trying to import a font to website I'm making using `@font-face`. But it won't work on **Chrome** what so ever, and sometimes it works on **Firefox** and sometimes not.

So I have no idea what is going on.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Proxima Nova";
    src: url('fonts/Proxima Nova.otf') format('opentype');
}
```

That almost worked in **Firefox** but **Chrome** didn't even want to display it, instead it showed some weird font with completely random size that had nothing to do with the css entered.

Then I tried this:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'proxnova';
        src: url('fonts/ProximaNovaSemibold.otf') format('opentype');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
}
```

This fixed sizing issues but now it doesn't show proper font anywhere. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use different font formats for different browsers. Sorry about that... :(

#### Source: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }
```

You can use a website like http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ to automatically generate everything you need.

Comment: Yeah but what if I have this font only as `otf` :( Does converting it by some means really work?

Comment: Yes, Font Squirrel will convert the font too.

Comment: OK. I'll try and give feedback. One question before that, in svg format url `webfont.svg#svgFontName` what is #svgFontName for? Don't remember ever using that syntax.

Comment: This is the id of the font used. "This is there because you can actually have multiple fonts embedded within the same SVG file, and you need to specify which one you want to use." And don't worry about that, everything will be covered for you through the generator.

Comment: Yeah the generator worked like a charm :)
I'll bookmark that site several times xD