# Chrome: Webfont is off by 1 character, but only sometimes

Tags: css, google-chrome, text, webfonts, text-rendering

Sometimes the text on my webpage will be off by a single character (in Chrome), I have attached a couple images below replicating the issue. I can reproduce this bug with the most success on this page: http://identity-dev.github.io/id-bower/docs/

Right

[image: Right]

Wrong

[image: Wrong]

Note: "Type" becomes "Sxod" and "Kit" becomes "Jhs"

It also seems as though the characters retain their original widths, so it's like it knows what characters should be there.

**Edit Added font-face code:**

```
@font-face{
    font-family: "Proxima";
    src: url('#{$font-path}/proxima-nova.eot' + '?#iefix');
    src: url('#{$font-path}/proxima-nova.svg') format("svg"),
         url('#{$font-path}/proxima-nova.eot' + '?#iefix') format("eot"),
         url('#{$font-path}/proxima-nova.woff') format("woff"),
         url('#{$font-path}/proxima-nova.ttf') format("truetype");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Where is the image ? Am i missing something?

Comment: Chrome is seriously buggy recently.

Comment: It looks like the font face issue. Can you switch to any other webfont and try once... Also, did you download the font and then created the font face from some other font face generator ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561079/font-face-completely-bugging, Check this... Also you can use http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ to generate the font face correctly...

Comment: This bug seems to have been fixed since Chrome Beta (45). Bisecting gives https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/3f87569bb10ffc8a925ed75147b783d089a2bc4f..922e867703071669f02a2bd6f33db52c400190f4, which contains a Blink roll: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+log/2ec92a3..a40fe3e. Out of the many commits, I guess that https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/643641e54750ef5df5776e798477eaeb8982fdfc fixed the problem.

Comment: What's the font face issue? I'm not sure how the fonts were generated, they've been in the project from before I joined. I'll try another webfont

Comment: @Saswata I can't use fontsquirrel to generate the font, because it says it's already a webfont. I'm trying to get another copy from our designers to see if maybe our version was corrupted

Comment: I reprocessed the font on fontsquirrel using the .otf instead of .ttf and it processed. However, the issue seems to be more prevalent and is off by two characters instead of 1.

Comment: @RobW That seems to be the issue. I just downloaded Chrome canary and the issue seems to be resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

try to select 'a' and apply the property

`letter-spacing: 1pt`